# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in points.php on line 46

Tags: php, html, this

I've already found a dozen of posts about this error, but I still cannot get this to work and I'm really confused. Could anyone give me a hand?

So I have an old bit of coding, but this wasn't coded that efficient since we had to use a new page for every different situation. I'm now trying to automate this, but unfortunately I can't get it to work.

First bit of the old coding that did work, points.html:

```
echo 
"<style>
body{
background-color:#0d161f;
text-align:center; 
padding:5px;
margin:auto;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:12px;
color:white;
}
#form{
text-align:center;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#form td{
padding:5px
}
</style>";

        if ( in_array( $this->memberData['member_group_id'], array(1, 2 ) ) ){
            }
else{
         echo  "<script> alert('You do not have access'); </script>";
        die();}
```

And now my new bit of coding that apparently doesn't work, while I'm pretty much using the same layout. Sorry for the long js coding, but I thought it might be what caused this problem, points.php:

```
<?php
require '/home/conn.req.php';
echo"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
<title>Points</title>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function changeSquad(str)
{
if (str=='')
  {
  // if blank, we'll set our innerHTML to be blank.
  document.getElementById(\"result\").innerHTML='';
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      // create a new XML http Request that will go to our generator webpage.
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {   // code for IE6, IE5
      // create an activeX object
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject(\"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\");
  }
  // on state change
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  // if we get a good response from the webpage, display the output
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
      document.getElementById(\"result\").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
 // use our XML HTTP Request object to send a get to our content php. 
xmlhttp.open(\"GET\",\"getSquad.php?squad=\"+str, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" media=\"screen\" />
</head>
<body>";


if ( in_array( $this->memberData['member_group_id'], array(1, 2 ) ) ){// Declares who have access.
    } else { echo  "<script> alert('You do not have access.'); </script>";
    die();}
```

I'm rather new to this, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your first piece of code isn't complete, is it?

Comment: It looks like the first part of the code is part of a class. `$this` is always referenced inside a class, and you'll need to figure out how to access that function from outside of the class.

Comment: Both pieces of coding aren't complete, it would be too much to post the whole code, so I just posted the first bit instead. I'm still trying to figure out where the class that references $this can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
if ( in_array( $this->memberData['member_group_id'], array(1, 2 ) ) ){// Declares who have access.
```

You are using `$this`, but you are not inside a class. I don't know the structure of your application, but you should probably change it to the variable that has the object with your member data info.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot, but that still leaves my question open why it did work without using it inside a class in the first bit of coding. That led me to believe it wasn't necessary to create $this inside a class.

Comment: It might be that your assumption is wrong and the old code actually WAS executed in a class context.

Comment: Well I really couldn't find that, as shown in my post above. Where would I be able to find that class context? The thing with this new coding is, is that the first time I run it, everything is loading fine, but after submitting it I keep getting this error. That confuses me.

Comment: The "points.html" file might get used as a template inside a template class, and the new "points.php" does not. It's really hard to guess what is wrong in your application because you gave not more information - and if you did, it would probably be too much for stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah I understand, well thanks a lot for your help I'll try to find out a solution.